# How to decide which config is used? Cloud or Local?

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

For a Azure cloud service, there're typically 2 configuration files.

- Serviceconfiguration.Cloud.cscfg
- ServiceConfiguration.Local.cscfg

When I press F5 in Visual Studio to run with local development environment, the Local one will be used.

When I publish it to Azure with Visual Studio, the Cloud one will be used.

Now I am building my cloud service with Team Foundation Build. Where can I configure which cscfg file the build engine should use?

### Add

With the publish wizard in VS2013, I can choose the config file to use:

[image]

But when I rebuild the cloud project, it always use the *.Local.cscfg file to generate the final 
ServiceConfiguration.cscfg. Like below:

[image]

**How can I make my local build use the .Cloud.cscfg file? My purpose is to config TFS build process to use the right cscfg file.**

Comment: Old, but potentially useful to you? http://slalomdotcom.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/building-and-deploying-windows-azure-projects-using-msbuild-and-tfs-2010/